# Angle between two lines on parametric surface

Tags: differential-geometry

I need to find what angle is between the lines $u=-v$ and $u=v$ on the surface:
$$r(u,v)=(u\cos(v), u\sin(v), 2v)$$
The only thing that comes to my mind is to put both line equations to the surface equation:
$$ \begin{align*}
r_1(v)&=(-v\cos(v),-v\sin(v), 2v)\\
r_2(v)&=(v\cos(v), v\sin(v), 2v)
\end{align*}$$
And then I need to find the angle between two curves at point $(0, 0, 0)$ because $u=0, v=0$.
Am I thinking right? Thanks for every answer.

Comment: since you have already substituted $u=-v$ and $u=v$ to the equation, then you have to find the angle between $r_1(v)$ and $r_2(v)$ as a function of $v$. You don't have to fix the value.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked.